# selecting one value sequentially from database

Tags: mysql, jsp

I am trying this . I have a table in mysql named "quotes" with columns (id,quote,author) with around 100 rows.
i want to select one quote daily and next day another quote sequentially .
how do i achieve this task. I want to get and display it in my webpage daily one quote.

Comment: [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `id` column is sequential (i.e. no gaps) from ***`x`*** to ***`y`***, you could use modular arithmetic:

```
SELECT * FROM quotes WHERE id = x + TO_DAYS(CURRENT_DATE) % (y - x + 1)
```